# How to get an object from Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app I have a `User` class that stores user information, I save it to `Firebase Realtime Database` as follows:

```
mDbReference.child("UserData").child(getUser().getUid()).setValue(user);
```

Now in another part of the app I want to retrieve that `User` object, but the app crashes. It works if I use `snapshot.getValue().toString()` but I want to save it in an `User` object like below:

```
Query usernameQuery = fHelper.getDbReference().child("UserData")
                        .orderByChild("userName")
                        .equalTo(userCredentialEditText.getText().toString().trim());
    
                usernameQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        User user = (User) snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        assert user != null;
                        Log.i("Snapshot", user.getUserEmail());
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                    }
                });
```

I get this error:

```
2021-04-19 22:40:34.769 15372-15372/com.outwire E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.outwire, PID: 15372
    java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:176)
        at com.outwire.login.LoginActivity$1.onDataChange(LoginActivity.java:173)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:191)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7565)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure you include the stack trace in your question. Also your title seems to suggest that you need a tutorial on reading data from Firebase, but actually you've encountered an error.

Comment: Have you checked whether `user.getUserEmail()` is null?

Comment: @HenryTwist yes, all the contents of the object are null, but if I use snapshot.getValue().toString() I can print the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your `onDataChange` needs to handle this list, even if there's only a single result, by looping over `snapshot.getChildren()`.

So something like:

```
Query usernameQuery = fHelper.getDbReference().child("UserData")
        .orderByChild("userName")
        .equalTo(userCredentialEditText.getText().toString().trim());

usernameQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            User user = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            assert user != null;
            Log.i("Snapshot", user.getUserEmail());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. `getChildren` is what you're looking for.  For future reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot

Comment: it worked perfectly, just one question. Why do I have to iterate when getting an object but not when I call getValue()?

Comment: Yikes, that was another typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes I caught that one, but why is it that I dont have to iterate when using getValue with no argument?

Comment: `getValue()` with no arguments on a snapshot like this will just give you a string representation of the map data in there. The first level you'll see in there is the key of the child node, which is dynamic and what the `for` loop iterates over.